# Why do empty matching regexps work differently in sed and grep?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

Using, for example, the tools on a Debian or Debian-derived system, a regex like `N*`, which could match the empty string, could result in a match in sed:

```
$ echo 'Hello' | sed 's/N*/ xx&xx /g'
  xxxx H xxxx e xxxx l xxxx l xxxx o xxxx
```

Which is the correct result of an empty match (thus the `xxxx` strings, no character in the middle `xx&xx`) before each string character (6 times in `Hello`. The trailing newline doesn't count, it is not matched).

And, if any character (or group of characters) would match it would appear between the `xx` and `xx`:

```
$ echo  'Hello' | sed 's/e*/ xx&xx /g'
 xxxx H xxexx l xxxx l xxxx o xxxx
```

However, the same regex in grep would **not** match the empty string:

```
$ echo 'Hello' | grep -o 'N*'
```

But will print **only** non-empty matches:

```
$ echo 'Hello' | grep -o 'e*'
e
```

Is there an additional internal rule in grep to avoid `empty` regex matches?

Comment: `grep` regexps find empty matches alright, but GNU `grep -o` as documented, doesn't report them. You'll  find that `echo a | grep 'x*'` outputs nothing but succeeds. ast-open's grep outputs empty  matches and runs in infinite loop when there are some.

Comment: Using debian grep, the `echo a | grep 'x*'` command from your comment does output `a`. I assume that you meant `echo a | grep -o 'x*'` which, yes has no output but an exit code of success, yes, while `echo a | grep 'xd*'` has a failure exit code. How does that help? @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did mean `each a | grep -o 'x*'` indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep -o` is documented in `grep --help` as

```
  -o, --only-matching       show only nonempty parts of lines that match
```

and [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html) as

> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.

So yes, there is an additional rule in `grep -o`: matches are only output if they are non-empty.

In `echo 'Hello' | grep -o 'N*'`, the regular expression matches (as can be seen by looking at the return code, or with `echo 'Hello' | grep 'N*'`), but because the matches are empty, nothing is output.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of 0-length string matches can be special cased in the code, or not. For instance the `sed` but not `perl`

```
$ echo aabb | sed 's/a*/X/g'
XbXbX
$ echo aabb | gsed 's/a*/X/g'
XbXbX
$ echo aabb | perl -ple 's/a*/X/g'
XXbXbX
```

[behavior probably comes from how vi behaved historically](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.bin/vi/ex/ex_subst.c#L556) as seen in the depths of `ex/ex_subst.c`:

```
    /*
     * !!!
     * It's possible to match 0-length strings -- for example, the
     * command s;a*;X;, when matched against the string "aabb" will
     * result in "XbXbX", i.e. the matches are "aa", the space
     * between the b's and the space between the b's and the end of
     * the string.  There is a similar space between the beginning
     * of the string and the a's.  The rule that we use (because vi
     * historically used it) is that any 0-length match, occurring
     * immediately after a match, is ignored.  Otherwise, the above
     * example would have resulted in "XXbXbX".  Another example is
     * incorrectly using " *" to replace groups of spaces with one
     * space.
```

(A different problem can be a zero-width matches that match forever; I'm pretty sure there's "just move to the next character..." code to prevent that, probably added *after* someone's CPU went to 100% a few times and a palm met a forehead.)

Both BSD and GNU `ed` fail on the `s/a*/X/g` expression, so the special behavior might be an `ex-vi` era change that escaped into `sed`?

```
$ echo aabb > foo
$ ed foo
5
s/a*/X/g
?
s/a*/X
Xbb
Q
```

Comment: See also the `sed 's/\<ab/X/g'` which turns `abab` into `XX` with some `sed` implementations (not easily avoidable when using the standard regex API).

Comment: Strange interpretation to ignore the "*0-length match, occurring immediately after a match*". Matches are non-overlapping, so there is no 0-length match which wouldn't already have been included in the previous match. With their logic you could as well say you find as many 0-length matches as you like between two matches …

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, wait what, how does that work? I could see it with `s/\<ab/:/g`, if the first `ab` turned into a `:`, giving `:ab` and there'd now be a word boundary before the second `ab`. But there shouldn't be one between an `X` and `ab`...? Right? I got `XX` with Busybox, so yeah, there must be some logic, but I can't see what it is...

Comment: @ilkkachu, after finding the first `ab`, `sed` resumes searching for the next occurrence of `\<ab` in what's after that: `ab`. At that point, `ab` is at the start so matching a word boundary. You don't get the same problem with `s/^ab/X/` because, there's a `REG_NOTBOL` flag in the standard regexp API for that, but no equivalent `REG_NOTBOW`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, oh, yes, right, of course it has to move over past the replaced part and not look at it again. Thanks again. IIRC `\<` isn't standard anyway, so it's perhaps not surprising there's no corresponding flag for it, and if there was a non-standard one, the tools wouldn't know to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'Hello' | grep -o 'N*'
$ echo $?
0
```

**It *does* match an empty substring of that input line, as shown by the exit status.**  (With a different pattern like `N`, we still get nothing on stdout, but an exit status of `1`, failure.)

`-o` makes it not *print* empty matches, but that's separate from whether the regex matches any input lines.  (And yes, we can distinguish that; if it had printed an empty-string match, it would output a newline after it each match, so there'd be a blank line before the prompt.  Or 6, one for each match.)

Without `-o`, it prints the whole matching line:

```
$ echo 'Hello' | grep  'N*'          # same as grep '' empty pattern
Hello
```

Comment: or there would be six blank lines, assuming the same behavior sed showed: that the zero-length match would be found once in every possible position